# Get date from event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, position, fullcalendar

I'm using **fullcalendar v2.0.2** and I'm making a copy/paste system for event. **I can copy** the event on right clicking with a little menu.

When I do a right click on the calendar, if it's a week, I calculate the position of each `.fc-agenda-days tr td` and `.fc-agenda-slots tr`. I have to add the vertical + horizontal scroll, get the slot duration, start date of current view ... It's a lot of stuff to consider, I can have a specific case maybe...

*I searched into the documentation for a helper, but I didn't find it... And I looked in the source code without success.*

My question is : "Is there an helper or a method for getting a date with a position or event ?"

Edit, I think I've found a way to do it, but it doesn't work :

```
{
    _pasteEventMenu: function(e, scope){
        var that = this;
        var date = null;

        var view = this._call('getView');
        var hoverListener = view.getHoverListener();
        hoverListener.start(function(coordinates){
            console.log('a', coordinates);
            console.log('Right click on ', view.cellToDate(coordinates).format('MMMM Do YYYY, hh:mm:ss'));
        }, e);
        hoverListener.stop();
        console.log('HERE');
    }
}
```

this code product the following out when I click on Monday October 13rd at 10:04 AM

`a Object {row: 61, col: 0}
Right click on  december 14 2015, 12:00:00
HERE`

Comment: Hard to understand what you're asking for. You say you can already copy an event by right clicking, so then what are you having trouble with?

Comment: Ah ok! When I do a right click on a free part of the calendar, I want to know what is the date/time where the user clicked

Comment: There's a method for that but I think it only fires on left mouse button. Really easy to extend to accept right mouse button too though, need help to do it?

Comment: Thanks for replying! How do you see this extends ? Using the SelectionManager or AgendaDayView/MonthView/BasicDayView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find a trick, if someone want it :

```
    var that = this;
    var date = null;

    var view = this._call('getView');
    var hoverListener = view.getHoverListener();
    hoverListener.start(function(coordinates){
        console.log('a', coordinates);
        var sec = (view.getMinTime()._milliseconds / 1000) + coordinates.row * (view.getSlotDuration()._milliseconds / 1000);
        console.log('Right click on ', view.cellToDate(0, coordinates.col).add(sec, 'seconds').format('MMMM Do YYYY, HH:mm:ss'));
    }, e, 'contextmenu');
    hoverListener.stop();
    console.log('HERE');
```